# Why answer sorting is off on this question

Tags: discussion, answers

Question: [Google Sheets execute script only in certain range on certain sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99113/google-sheets-execute-script-only-in-certain-range-on-certain-sheet)

It opens with sorted by "Highest score (default)":[image]

but, answers are not arranged by highest score, see screenshot (answer with -1 score is displayed first, next answer has score 2).

There is more - if change sorting to "Date modified (newest first)"

[image]

answer with modified date "Oct 5, 2016 at 20:27" is displayed first, next answer has edited date "Oct 8, 2016 at 4:01".

Changing sorting to "Date created (oldest first)" also gives wrong sort result:
[image]

first question answered Oct 5, 2016 at 20:27, next answer is answered Oct 5, 2016 at 15:00.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Unlike some SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369568/162827), in Web Apps SE, the accepted answer is *pinned* at the top of the list of answers.

Comment: thanks, while this is correct answer, let me say how I'm surprised

Comment: @Kos No body have opened the discussion yet.